# Mutual reference of local interfaces in ABAP impossible?

Tags: oop, interface, abap

Im trying to implement a version of the observer pattern based on interfaces in ABAP. I have the following two interfaces:

```
REPORT z_observer.

INTERFACE observer.
  METHODS:
    update IMPORTING VALUE(sub) TYPE subject.
ENDINTERFACE.

INTERFACE subject.
  METHODS:
    register_observer IMPORTING VALUE(obs) TYPE REF TO observer,
    remove_observer IMPORTING VALUE(obs) TYPE REF TO observer,
    notify_observer.
ENDINTERFACE.
```

This does not compile with an error message that either `subject` or `object` is unknown depending on their order of declaration. It it possible to have mutually referencing (local) classes/interfaces in ABAP. Am I missing something important?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this before the observer definition:

```
INTERFACE subject DEFERRED.
```

(see the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapinterface_deferred.htm))